# Collecting indexed statisticts from list of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a list of objects, ex.

```
var data = [{a: 'data1', b: 'subdata1'}, {a: 'data2', b: 'subdata2'}, {a: 'data1', b: 'subdata3'}, {a: 'data1', b: 'subdata1'}]
```

(note the objects have other attributes too)

I'm looking to extract some condensed details of this list with a result:

```
[{type: 'data1', list: [{subtype: 'subdata1', count: 2}, {subtype: 'subdata3', count: 1}]}, {type: 'data2', list: [{subtype: 'data2', count: 1}]}]
```

I have been able to count the type (or subtype) with reduce:

```
data.reduce((lst, item) => { lst[item.type] = lst[item.type] + 1 || 1; return lst; }, {});
```

but, this isn't exactly the structure or complete detail I'm looking to achieve. I can obviously do the work manually with a for loop, but I'm hoping to understand map, reduce, etc. better for a cleaner/simpler implementation.

Comment: This isn't very useful. The example is overly basic and less than the example I've already given. I'm not ignorant to the docs, but I'm trying to do something that combines usage I haven't done before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a nested lookup table, (a -> b -> count), then you can iterate over that and build the result:

```
  const table = {};

  for(const { a, b } of data) {
    if(!table[a]) table[a] = {};
    if(!table[a][b]) table[a][b] = 0;
    table[a][b]++;
  }

  const result = Object.entries(table)
     .map(([type, entries]) => ({ type, list: Object.entries(entries).map(([ subtype, count ]) => ({ subtype, count })), }));
```

Yes, one *could* write that as a functional chain:

```
   const result = Object.entries(
     data.reduce(
        ((table, { a, b }) => (table[a] || (table[a] = {}))[b] = (table[a][b] || 0) + 1, table),
        {}
     )
   ).map(([type, entries]) =>  ({
      type, 
      list: Object.entries(entries).map(([ subtype, count ]) => ({ subtype, count })),
   }));
```

But IMO thats less readable.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the output format to simplify it a bit and combined your lookup idea with a more simplified all object (no array) reduce version.